# How can I make one folder different in Windows 10 and OneDrive?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

I have many folders in OneDrive. Every time I open the OneDrive folder in Windows 10 I use maybe 2 of those many folders most of the time. How can I make these 2 folders appear differently than the others so as soon as I open OneDrive I can see them quickly?

Comment: You need a folder naming convention to help you with this. There is no automation to differentiate.

Comment: Do you mean to change the folder icon? If so - yes, you can do it. Not sure if it will synchronize to other computers, though.

Comment: @markalex yeah that could be one way to change the icon. Is there any other way? Can I for example make one folder bigger than the rest?

Comment: I'm not aware of such functionality in default Explorer in windows 10.